Specifying input port in custom LeafSystem_
I am trying to author a leaf system for use in the DirectCollocation class. I have looked at the examples, which lead me in the direction of a templated LeafSystem_. I encounter an error that requires me to specify the input_port_index optional argument, which once added results in an error.
I am using Python 3.11.4 with Drake 1.25.0 on Ubuntu 23.04 (thru WSL2). How would I go about fixing this?
This is my current solution:
# LeafSystem includes
from pydrake.systems.framework import LeafSystem_
from pydrake.systems.scalar_conversion import TemplateSystem
from pydrake.autodiffutils import AutoDiffXd
from pydrake.symbolic import Expression
from pydrake.planning import DirectCollocation
from pydrake.solvers import MathematicalProgram, Solve

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


@TemplateSystem.define("SlidingBlockSystem_")
def SlidingBlockSystem_(T):
    class Impl(LeafSystem_[T]):
        # Args: (self, <args>, converter=None, <kwargs>)
        def _construct(self, converter=None, mass=2.0, damping=0.5):
            LeafSystem_[T].__init__(self, converter=converter)
            self._mass = mass
            self._damping = damping

            # Ports
            self.DeclareContinuousState(1, 1, 0)
            self._force_port = self.DeclareVectorInputPort(
                "force", size=1)
            self.DeclareVectorOutputPort(
                "state", size=2, calc=self.DoCalcTimeDerivatives)

        def _construct_copy(self, other, converter=None):
            Impl._construct(self, converter=converter,
                            mass=other._mass, damping=other._damping)

        def DoCalcTimeDerivatives(self, context, derivatives):
            # x = context.get_continuous_state_vector().GetAtIndex(0)
            xdot = context.get_continuous_state_vector().GetAtIndex(1)
            force = self._force_port.Eval(context).GetAtIndex(0)

            xddot = (force - self._damping*xdot)/self._mass

            derivatives[0] = xdot
            derivatives[1] = xddot

    return Impl


def main():
    N = 25
    tf = 5.0

    sliding_block = SlidingBlockSystem_[AutoDiffXd]()
    context = sliding_block.CreateDefaultContext()

    print(sliding_block.get_input_port().get_index())

    dircol = DirectCollocation(
        sliding_block, context, num_time_samples=N, minimum_time_step=0.05, maximum_time_step=0.5,
        input_port_index=sliding_block.get_input_port().get_index())
    
    # Rest of code...

This is the error I receive:
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. pydrake.planning.DirectCollocation(system: pydrake.systems.framework.System, context: pydrake.systems.framework.Context, num_time_samples: int, minimum_time_step: float, maximum_time_step: float, input_port_index: Union[pydrake.systems.framework.InputPortSelection, pydrake.systems.framework.InputPortIndex] = <InputPortSelection.kUseFirstInputIfItExists: -2>, assume_non_continuous_states_are_fixed: bool = False, prog: pydrake.solvers.MathematicalProgram = None)


The system argument to the DirectCollocation constructor must be of type System (which is shorthand for System_[float]); it cannot be of type System_[AutoDiffXd].
Something like sliding_block = SlidingBlockSystem_[float]() should work.
